# Socket communication in JavaFX

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, javafx

I'm trying to develop an email server which is able to manage three or more clients. Now I'm focusing only on the first client. The mechanism I'm using is this: The client sends its email address (a String) to the server, so he can get into the right directory and extracts the texts from the .txt (which are the emails). This is the structure of the Server directory:

```
                                  $package
                                     |
                  +------------+----------------------------+
                  |            |                            |
             Server.java  ServerController.java       email@email.com/            
                                                            |
                                                            +
                                                   +--------|---------+
                                                 1.txt     2.txt     3.txt
```

This is the ServerController file, which is the one that executes the threads:

```
public class ServerController {

@FXML
private TextArea textarea;

public void initModel() {
    try {
        int i = 1;
        ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(5000);
        while (true) {
            Socket incoming = s.accept(); // si mette in attesa di richiesta di connessione e la apre
            textarea.setText("Waiting for connections");
            Runnable r = new ThreadedEchoHandler(incoming, i);
            new Thread(r).start();
            i++;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class ThreadedEchoHandler implements Runnable {

    private Socket incoming;
    private int counter;

    /**
     * Constructs a handler.
     *
     * @param i the incoming socket
     * @param c the counter for the handlers (used in prompts)
     */
    public ThreadedEchoHandler(Socket in, int c) {
        incoming = in;
        counter = c;
    }

    public void run() {
        String nomeAccount = "";
        try {
            //PHASE 1: The server receives the email
            try {
                InputStream inStream = incoming.getInputStream();
                Scanner in = new Scanner(inStream);
                nomeAccount = in.nextLine(); //ricevo il nome
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ServerController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } finally {
                try {
                    incoming.close();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(ServerController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
            }

            //PHASE 2: I'm getting all the emails from the files
            File dir = new File(nomeAccount);
            String[] tmp = new String[5];
            ArrayList<Email> arr = new ArrayList<Email>();
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            int i = 0;
            for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
                if (file.isFile()) {
                    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
                    input = new Scanner(file);
                    while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                        tmp[i++] = input.nextLine();
                    }
                    input.close();
                }
                Date data = df.parse(tmp[4]);
                arr.add(new Email((Integer.parseInt(tmp[0])), tmp[1], nomeAccount, tmp[2], tmp[3], data));
                i = 0;
            }

            //PHASE 3: The server sends the ArrayList to the client
            try {
                ObjectOutputStream objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(incoming.getOutputStream());
                objectOutput.writeObject(arr);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServerController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                incoming.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(ServerController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I divide it into phases to better understand the mechanism. In the client I've a DataModel which is the one who memorize the email list and that establish the connection with the socket. This is the code:

```
public void loadData() throws IOException {
    Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5000);
    System.out.println("I've created the socket");
    ArrayList<Email> email = new ArrayList<Email>();

    //PHASE 1: The client sends a string to the server
    try {
        InputStream inStream = s.getInputStream();
        OutputStream outStream = s.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outStream, true /* autoFlush */);
        out.print(account); //Sends account name

        //PHASE 2: The client receives the ArrayList with the emails
        ObjectInputStream objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream()); //Error Line!
        try {
            Object object = objectInput.readObject();
            email = (ArrayList<Email>) object;
            System.out.println(email.get(1));
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("The list list has not come from the server");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } finally {
        s.close();
    }

    //Casting the arrayList
    emailList = FXCollections.observableArrayList(email);

    //Sorting the emails
    Collections.sort(emailList, new Comparator<Email>() {
        public int compare(Email o1, Email o2) {
            if (o1.getData() == null || o2.getData() == null) {
                return 0;
            }
            return o1.getData().compareTo(o2.getData());
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is that when I execute the server I don't get any error but the GUI doesn't load and on the prompt I cannot see any output. If I execute the Client (while the server is running) I only get the message `System.out.println("I've created the socket");` but nothing happens after that. What should I modify to let the two sockets communicates?

Comment: Unrelated to the issue: Your `Comparator` does not fulfill the transitivity requirement of the relation: Let `o1` and `o2` be objects with non-null data that yields a value != 0 when compared. Let `o3` be an object with `null` as data. `compare(o1, o3) == 0` and `compare(o2, o3) == 0` imply `compare(o1, o2) == 0` which is not the case.

Comment: I am guessing your `ServerController` design is not correct. At first glance, I see ` while (true) {` in `initModel`. This is probably going to freeze your program.

Comment: I don’t think you want `new Scanner(System.in)` in a JavaFX application.

Comment: @Sedrick without the while(true) how can I manage illimitate thread?

Comment: @VGR how do I read into the file without the scanner?

Comment: The problem isn’t the Scanner.  The problem is your use of System.in.  You don’t even need that statement, since the very next line is replacing that variable’s value with a different Scanner.

Comment: Never run long running task on JavaFX UI Thread. https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm.

Answer (score 0):

Using Sockets is bad idea at all. You don't need direct connection.
It's better to use something like REST service with GET and POST.

so you can manage any clients count. Just send response to get and post.
Also you can use tokens.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to use sockets for my project.